# geometric visualisation of an arbitrary p - chain

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the paper I am reading, the author has not provided a "methodology" for visualising what a $p$-chain looks like; a google search has not yield anything to assist me in this either. 
[Persistent Homology: An Introduction and
a New Text Representation for Natural Language Processing](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jerryzhu/pub/homology.pdf)

To get started, the definition for a $p$-chain is as follows:

> Definition: A $p$-chain is a subset of $p$-simplicies in a simplicial complex K

But how does this subset looks like? The author provided a couple of images

[image]

with the left image being a 2 - chain and the right being a 1 - chain? How do I convince myself of this?

Comment: The author of that text seems to use mod 2 coefficients. In that case it just that simple: a chain is just an arbitrary bunch of simplices in a given dimension. On the left you have two triangles. On the right you have two edges.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek How does your explanation fit together with what is shown? I'm having difficulty reconciling everything.

Comment: Let's take the right picture, say it is the boundary of a tetrahedron, so a simplicial complex with 4 vertices, 6 edges and 4 2-dim faces. Out of those your blue 1-chain consists of the two blue edges.